# JointJS scaling issues with display:none

Tags: jointjs

I'm trying to embed a jointjs diagram inside a bootstrap carousel and running into issues.  Everything works fine if the diagram is on the initial/active pane but if it's one any other pane the elements and links scale in an odd fashion and the links connect at the incorrect sides of the elements.  I've narrowed this down to being a property of the svg being rendered into a div that is set for display:none.  A JSFiddle that reproduces the issue using the jointjs tutorial code and some simple css is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/L2wev6xc/4/

HTML

```
<button id="showsvg" type="button">Show Diagram</button>
<div id="myholder" class="hidden"></div>
```

CSS

```
#myholder {
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.hidden {
  /* comment out the line below and run again to see the different scaling and links */
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
// cut paste entire jointjs tutorial here

$("#showsvg").click(function () {
  $("#myholder").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

This does not happen if i use the visibility property, only display.  Also, for the diagram in the jsfiddle above the scaling things are slightly off but in a much larger and more complex diagram things get dramatically worse.

Answer (score 2):

The JointJS paper must be visible when element are rendered. If the paper is not in the live DOM (but detached, e.g. somewhere in a document fragment or displayed as 'none') than the dimension of the elements are not known yet. Browsers only know dimensions of elements that are in the RenderTree (which is constructed from the live DOM). This then creates issues when JointJS is trying to position certain SVG elements based on the position of others. The only way to work around this is to add elements into the graph (and therefore populate the paper) once the paper gets visible (and is displayed).

Comment: This is indeed the reason. There are issues reported for any major browser regarding this. It should nonetheless work if you switch from `display: none` to `visibility: hidden` on the target `div`